# Fair Coin Probability HTH

Tags: probability, expected-value

> We toss a fair coin and record the outcome as a sequence of H and T. Let $X$ be the number of tosses till $HTH$ (heads immediately followed by tails immediately followed by heads) appear for the first time. Find $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

**My Work**

For $X$ tosses, if $X=0,1$ then the $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$, right?

For $X>2$
Let $I_k=\begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if we get } HTH \\ 0 \quad \text{o.w.} \end{cases}$

Then the $\mathbb{E}(X)=X*\frac{1}{8}$?

[image]

Comment: You can't start by saying "if $X=0,1$", because $X$ is the result of your observations and not something specified ahead of time.  For example if the tosses are $HHHTTHHTHTTHH\cdots$, then $X$ takes the value $9$.  Hope I'm not being rude but I think you have serious misunderstandings here and you need to talk to your teacher if possible, not ask random people online.

Comment: very useful advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can be in one of 3 states:

We are at least 3 filps away from completing the $HTH$ sequence.  Either we have just started, or the last two flips were TT.

We are potentially two flips from completing the sequence.  The last flip was a heads

Our last two flips were $HT$ and we are one flip away.

Let A be the expected number of flips from being in the first condition to completing the game, B be the expected number of flips from being in the second condition to completing the game, B be the expected number of flips from being in the third condition to completing the game

If we are in the 3rd state with 50% likelihood we complete on the next flip.  With 50% likelihood we move to the first state in the next filp

$C = \frac 12 + \frac12 (A+1)$

Using similar logic we can generate these two equations.

$A = \frac 12 (B+1) + \frac12 (A+1)\\
B = \frac 12 (C+1)+ \frac12 (B+1)$

This gives us a system of linear equations.  Solve and find $A$